# Excel VBA add attachment with changing paths

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

I cannot get the Attachment.Add line to work. pdfadd is basically a string of pdf path. This code mass email to each personal with a PDF that is specific to him defined in column E as a text. Why cant this code work? I have read through others code but cant get it to work. Only this particular attachment line is not working. Many thanks!

```vb
    Sub send_mass_email()
    
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim name, email, body, subject, copy, pdfadd As String
        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        
        
        body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text
        
        
        i = 2
        'Loop down name column starting at row 2 column 1
        Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
            
            name = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")(0)
            email = Cells(i, 2).Value
            subject = Cells(i, 3).Value
            copy = Cells(i, 4).Value
            pdfadd = Cells(i, 5).Value
            
            body = Replace(body, "C1", name)
        
            
            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OutMail
                 .to = email
                 .cc = copy
                 .subject = subject
                 .body = body
                 .Attachments.Add (pdfadd)
                 .display
                 '.Send
            End With
        
            body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text 'reset body text
            
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        
        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
        
        'MsgBox "Email(s) Sent!"
        
    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: can you give us an example of what is the content pf cells(i,5) = pdfadd?

Comment: "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\PDFlist\Test PDF (CustomerName).pdf" It looks like this for column E, each customer name is different for each PDF, the error i receive if I run the attachment line is Run time error '-2147024773 (8007007b) Automation error, the filename, directory name or volume syntax is incorrect. However if I replace the pdfadd with that path name it works

Comment: try removing the brackets

Comment: @ike Same error Sir

Comment: Then check - while debugging, if variable pdfadd has really the value you expect (btw: you need to declare each variable explicitly -->  `Dim name as string, email as string, body as string, subject as string, copy as string, pdfadd As String`

Comment: Yes Sir, I just added a picture to the question bottom for your use

Comment: you have to remove the quotation marks!!!

Comment: Oh yes, hahaha it works thanks @ike! I didnt even noticed that

Comment: You could also put the `Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` line before the start of the Do loop - no need to set it on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method creates a new attachment in the `Attachments` collection. The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment. So, you need to make sure a correct file path without forbidden symbols is used in the code. But it seems in your case - quotation marks.