# How can I attach a file where path and file name are cell values?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create an email with an attachment.

It will be used by multiple users so the path is different. Users will enter the path in a cell. Same goes for the file name. Users will enter it in a cell.

My current code:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim strbody As String
    Dim xStrFile As String
    Dim xFilePath As String
    Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xFileDlgItem As Variant
    Dim xOutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim xMailOut As Outlook.MailItem
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xMailOut = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    If xFileDlg.Show = -1 Then
        With xMailOut
            .To = ""
            .CC = Rows(2).Columns(4).Value
            .BCC = Rows(2).Columns(3).Value
            .Subject = Rows(2).Columns(5).Value
            .Body = Rows(2).Columns(6).Value
            For Each xFileDlgItem In xFileDlg.SelectedItems
                .Attachments.Add xFileDlgItem
            Next xFileDlgItem
            .Display
        End With
    End If
    Set xMailOut = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If user input file name and path then why you are using `Application.FileDialog`? Use cell reference instead.

Comment: How can I make the code?

Comment: See [add attachment with changing paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73048588). When you concatenate path and file name ensure there is a \ before the file name.